# Include HTML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When using PHP, I write:

`<?php include('foo.html');?>
<?php include('bar.html');?>`

I tried jQuery, but I am not satisfied as I have to specify the container where I have to load the HTML page.

```
$('.container').load('foo.html');
```

I need the same result as PHP, but using JavaScript. And load more than one file.

Any help

Comment: What about reading the docs?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Agnelio, if an answer provided a solution, please accept it so the post is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I found something that might match what you are looking for

[How can I load multiple html files from a folder into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872670/4298746)

[Query load multiple html files in one element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605725/4298746)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO. Please provide the essence of the solution here.